# Spark3 interperter is not launching from zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have installed zeppelin locally on my laptop. I have built it from source, my configured spark version is 3.x.
Whenever i'm trying to create a spark notebook the spark and try to execute a simple line, I get this error:

```
    ERROR [2020-09-15 23:40:17,033] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1215078524-Worker-1} 
     SparkInterpreter.java[open]:121) - Fail to open SparkInterpreter
     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.spark2CreateContext(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:301)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.createSparkContext(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:230)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala212Interpreter.open(SparkScala212Interpreter.scala:90)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:106)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.Interpreter.getInterpreterInTheSameSessionByClassName(Interpreter.java:355)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.Interpreter.getInterpreterInTheSameSessionByClassName(Interpreter.java:366)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.open(PySparkInterpreter.java:89)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:760)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:668)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:130)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(FIFOScheduler.java:39)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.defaultNumHeapArena()I**
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyUtils.createPooledByteBufAllocator(NettyUtils.java:161)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyUtils.getSharedPooledByteBufAllocator(NettyUtils.java:138)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.<init>(TransportClientFactory.java:107)
        at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createClientFactory(TransportContext.java:142)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.<init>(NettyRpcEnv.scala:77)
```